# MVC LINQ Join three tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables:

```
*USERS*
ID | USERNAME | ...

*SERVICE_NAME*
ID | SERVICE_NAME

*USER_SERVICES*
ID | ID_USER | ID_SERVICE
```

From the table `*USER_SERVICES*`, I can check if the user has the services enabled.
This is my LINQ so far but it returns me only users who have actually **at least one** service enabled.

```
        var resultsServices = from p in USER_SERVICES
                      group p.ID_SERVICE by p.ID_USER into g
                      select new { ID_USER = g.Key, Services = g.ToList() };


        users = (from user in USERS
            join service in resultsServices on user.ID equals service.ID_USER
            where user.ID == service.ID_USER
            select new
            {
                user,
                service.Services
            });
```

How can I return all users, even if they do not have any service enabled that it "return null" or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: Apart from the clear duplication, you should **not** perform joins in LINQ. It's a clear sign that the classes are wrong. You should define relations between the entities so that the User class has a Services colletion with Service instances he has enabled. This would allow you to simply load the User and get all the related entities as well. No joins needed